# What kind of analysis to use in SPSS for finding out groups/grouping?

Tags: cluster-analysis, spss

My research question is about elderly people and I have to find out underlying groups. The  data comes from a questionnaire. I have thought about cluster analysis, but the thing is that I would like to search perceived health and which things affect on the perceived health, e.g. what kind of groups of elderly rank their health as bad.

I have some 30 questions I would like to check with the analysis, to see if for example widows have better or worse health than the average. I also have weights in my data so I need to use complex samples.

How can I use an already existing function, or what analysis should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The key challenge you have to solve first is to specify a similarity measure. Once you can measure similarity, various clustering algorithms become available.

But questionnaire data doesn't make a very good vector space, so you can't just use Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate clusters using SPSS, standard options include: k-means, hierarhical cluster analysis, or 2-step. I have some general [notes on cluster analysis in SPSS here](http://web.psych.unimelb.edu.au/jkanglim/03clusterandfactoranalysis.pdf). See from slide 34.

If you want to see if widows differ in their health, then you need to form a measure of health and compare means on that measure between widows and non-widows (presumably using a between groups t-test). If you have 30 questions related to health, then you may want to do a factor analysis to see how the items group together.

If you are trying to develop  a general model of whats predicts perceived health then there are a wide range of modelling options available. Multiple regression would be an obvious starting point. If you have many potential predictors then you have a lot of choices regarding whether you are going to be testing particular models or doing a more data driven model building approach.

More generally, it sounds like you need to clarify the aims of your analyses and the particular hypotheses that you want to test.